# Hago reset css pero se sigue viendo todo distinto dependiendo del navegador

Tags: css, responsive

He hecho el siguiente reset css:

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Pero la página se me sigue viendo distinta entre navegadores, sobretodo lo respecto a margenes respecto al borde al reducir el ancho de la página.

¿ Está anticuado el reset css o que problema más hay ???

Comment: ¿Porqué hacer reset? Deberías hacer una normalización, es lo que realmente te va a permitir renderizar de forma bastante aceptable lo mismo en la mayoría de navegadores. Puedes leer [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Muchas librerías y framworks para web lo usan, entre ellos Bootstrap. Saludos

Comment: No resetees, mejor normaliza usa esta herramienta: [normalize css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: Yo probaría a poner después del normalize, al que también mucha gente le pone un reset como el que tu has puesto por si las moscas, en el body la sentencia box-sizing: border-box; para restringir aún más lo que hacen los navegadores.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices mejor normalize.css:
https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Y añadas lo que añadas, recuerda tener lo siguiente:

```
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Esa propiedad influye sobre el modelo de caja, algo importante para organizar mejor los nodos a la hora de maquetar.

Un saludo.